# Como adicionar cabeçalho e rodapé no mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou a fazer um trabalho em que tenho de gerar um PDF pelo mPDF e ele gera correctamente, mas apartir do momento que adiciono cabeçalho ou rodapé, deixa de funcionar e não gera o PDF, o objectivo era adicionar paginação ao rodapé, visto que é um dos requisitos pedidos já procurei outras alternativas na internet e baseiam-se todas no mesmo, será que me podem ajudar ? Em baixo deixo o código.

```
<?php

include("pdf/mpdf.php");

$servidor = "localhost"; $user = "root"; $password = ""; $database = "relatorios"; $idrelatorio = $_GET["idrelatorio"]; $con = mysqli_connect($servidor, $user, $password, $database);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `relatorios` WHERE `id_relatorio`=" . $idrelatorio; $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$pagina = "

    <h2>Relatório Dinâmico</h2>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id_categoria = $row["id_categoria"];
    $data_inicio = $row["data_inicial"];
    $data_fim = $row["data_final"];
    if ($row["id_categoria"] == 1) {
        $categoria = "Batismos";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 2) {
        $categoria = "Catecúmenos";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 3) {
        $categoria = "Óbitos";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 4) {
        $categoria = "Crismas";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 5) {
        $categoria = "Catequese";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 6) {
        $categoria = "Documentos";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 7) {
        $categoria = "Famílias";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 8) {
        $categoria = "Intenções de Missa";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 9) {
        $categoria = "Paroquianos";
    } else if ($row["id_categoria"] == 10) {
        $categoria = "Casamentos";
    }

    $pagina .= "
                   Categoria: " . $categoria . "<br>
                   Nome: " . $row['nome'] . "<br>
                   Descrição: " . $row['descricao'] . "<br>"; }


$sqldadoscampos = "SELECT `NomeCampo`,`SQLCampo` FROM `relatoriodinamicocampos` rdc, `campos_categorias` c WHERE rdc.`idRelatorio`=" . $idrelatorio . " and rdc.`idCampo`=c.`idCampo`"; $resultdadoscampos = mysqli_query($con, $sqldadoscampos); $sqlultimo = "SELECT ";

$arrayCamposDescricao = array(); $arrayCamposValue = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultdadoscampos)) {
    $sqlultimo .= " `" . $row["SQLCampo"] . "` ,";
    $arrayCamposDescricao[] = $row["NomeCampo"];
    $arrayCamposValue[] = $row["SQLCampo"]; }

$sqlultimo = substr($sqlultimo, 0, -1);

if ($id_categoria == 1) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `baptisms` WHERE 1 and `baptism_date` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria == 2) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `catechumens` WHERE 1 and `data_catecumenatos` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria == 3) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `deaths` WHERE 1 and `data_catecumenatos` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria == 4) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `chrisms` cs, `chrisms_entities` ce WHERE cs.`id_crismas`=ce.`id_crismas` and `data_crisma` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria
== 5) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `catechisms` c,`catechisms_student` cs WHERE c.`id_catequese`=cs.`id_catequese` and `inscription_date` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria
== 6) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `documents` WHERE 1"; } else if ($id_categoria == 7) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `families` f,`families_persons` fp WHERE f.`id_familias`=fp.`id_familias` and `creation_date` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria
== 8) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `mass_intentions` WHERE 1 and `intention_date` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria == 9) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `parishioners` WHERE 1 and `birthdate` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; } else if ($id_categoria == 10) {
    $sqlultimo .= " FROM `weddings` WHERE 1 and `wedding_date` BETWEEN '" . $data_inicio . "' and '" . $data_fim . "'"; }

$pagina .= "<br/><br/>"; $resultdadosutlimocampos = mysqli_query($con, $sqlultimo); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultdadosutlimocampos)) {

    $cont = 0;
    foreach ($arrayCamposValue as $result) {
        $pagina .= "<div><b>" . $arrayCamposDescricao[$cont] . ":</b> " . $row[$result] . "</div>";
        $cont++;
    }

    $pagina .= "<br/><br/>"; }

$mpdf = new mPDF('', '', '', '', 30, 30, 40, 50);

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div>LDS</div>');

$footer = "<table width=\"1000\">
                   <tr>
                     <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>";

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);


$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina); $mpdf->Output();


exit; ?>
```

Se eu não tiver o "SetHTMLFooter" e o "SetHTMLHeader" funciona bem, apartir do momento que adiciono essas linhas deixa de funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Quando duvidas assim surgirem não exite em olhar na documentação [oficial](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-2.html).

O link acima tem esse exemplo (que se encaixa nas suas necessidades):

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

// Define the Header/Footer before writing anything so they appear on the first page
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">
    My document
</div>');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">{DATE j-m-Y}</td>
        <td width="33%" align="center">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">My document</td>
    </tr>
</table>');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Você só precisa ficar atenta ao uso de namespaces (caso você nÃO utilize adapte para require) e ao output.

Comment: Eu no exemplo acima já estou a fazer como esse exemplo que me mostrou e não funciona...